# Working with GridView and GridLayout

Tags: android, layout, gridview

Now I have a GridView in my activity which I fill with numbers from a txt file (and inserting via an adapter). 
This works perfectly, but I want to add some buttons at the bottom to enable input from the user.
But when I add a button, I get this weird result.

[image: Wrong result]

But the result I want to have is this:

[image: Wanted result]

How can I accomplish this?
This is my current layout XML code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".LevelSpelen" >

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:columnWidth="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:numColumns="3"
    android:verticalSpacing="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

</GridView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/gridView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
    android:text="" />
```

What do you guys suggest? A gridLayout or something else?
Please let me know!

Comment: where do you fill your gridview?

Comment: use GridView, specify `android:numColumns=5`

Comment: @A.S. After I change from one activity to another in the method onCreate(), just after the setContentView method

Comment: I'll give you the hint to try it with a custom GridView Adapter, explained in this tut http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-gridview-example/

Comment: @GopalRao Awesome, that worked! But how can I specify that my GridView takes up as less space as possible (to work on smaller devices)?

Comment: But sorry why are you even trying to add a button, you can get the clicked grid item in a onItemClickListener fpr your gridview. Sorry do not get it

Comment: @A.S.I want to make some kind of maze game. You start at a point and use the arrows keys (=buttons) to move through the maze. Now the maze is just an array with numbers, but the structure of the path should be visible

Comment: @Matt dynamically get the screen width and set width of each item in to 1/5th of screen width or you can specify the width using `dimens` resources by specifying values under respective folders such as values values-sw600dp etc etc...

Comment: @GopalRao Nice, I'll try that. But there isn't a property that resizes the GridView to be as small as possible?

Comment: @Matt `int w = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
  int h = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
  final int size = Math.min(w, h);
  ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = gridView.getLayoutParams();
  params.width = (int) (size * 0.80); // 80% of screen
  gridView.setLayoutParams(params);`